# All in one Django/Python editor

Tags: python, django, ide

I know this is probably a question that is asked a ton on here but I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm a JAVA developer that is learning Python and Django and I'm looking for a good development environment.  I would like to be able to edit python code, css, html and javascript all in the same editor if possible.  I have been trying out both Komodo and pydev.  I like Komodo so far.  Being a JAVA developer I am very comfortable in Eclipse but it just doesn't feel like it might be the right environment to be doing Python development in.  I was wondering if anyone had good recommendations.  I also have heard about CODA, TextMate and SubEthaEdit.  I should mention that I'm doing my development work on Mac.  I know these things are really opinionated but didn't know if there was some kind of "industry" standard for Python/Django development on the Mac.

I have done the normal searches on stackoverflow and looked through this post as well [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python).  I just haven't found an answer that seemed to fit my situation......

Comment: I was going to suggest geany until I read "Mac"...

Comment: Looks like you can get geany for the mac, albeit a couple of minor versions behind - http://geany.darwinports.com/ I haven't tried that one before, and I think I'll check it out myself.

Comment: @Alex: The problem isn't availability of geany itself, the problem is availability of a native version of GTK+.

Comment: @Ignacio So, does that just mean it won't run smoothly on a Mac? Anyhow, I installed it for Linux and am impressed. I love the function and property pane. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Alex: It means that you have to run the X server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your familiar with eclipse, by all means try Pydev first. I was the opposite, I was/am a Python developer who switched to Java. There was no real difference between using Eclipse for Java and Eclipse for Python (Pydev), you still get inline docs, debugging, code completion, the whole bit. You also get a lot of great stuff along with it like subversive, mylyn, aptana, etc.

Comment: +1 on pydev; general eclipse bloat aside it works well and gets frequent updates/improvements.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of Mac developers use TextMate because it has a lot of creature features.

If you're working with big files and need speed, look at BBEdit - it's amazing how fast it can find/replace stuff.

If you want an editor that is close to Eclipse, but not a full-blown Java-based/oriented IDE, Komodo [Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads) (open source) or [IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/downloads) (commercial) is pretty good, though I can usually get it to crash within an hour. I think it doesn't like me.

My primary editor is vim or gvim, depending on what hosting system I am on. It handles every language, runs on Mac, Linux and Windows, and is very customizable and, when you're used to it, can be very fast. I spend 99% of my editing time in gvim and it's the first or second thing I install on a machine, along with my customized setup and favorite fonts and plugins.

Answer (score 2):

As you're familiar with Eclipse, Pydev is a good choice.

Komodo is the only IDE/Editor I know which supports Django Template Language syntax highlighting. But it's really so rudimentary that I think you can live without it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on OSX and I've recently tried out http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ and it looks pretty good, but I can't quite get comfy with it -- but if you're familiar with Eclipse, then you might like it.

Personally, I find that I'm plenty productive with TextMate and a few of the Textmate [Python/Django bundles](http://netcetera.org/cgi-bin/tmbundles.cgi)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give Geany a try.  Its very easy to use and is definitely one of my most favorite IDE's I have ever used.